# Matrix reaised to an exponent

Tags: matrices

$If\quad the\quad matrix\quad A\quad =\quad \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \quad -1 \\ -1 & \quad \quad 1 \end{bmatrix}\\ \qquad Then\quad { A }^{ n+1 }\quad =\quad ?$

**My effort**

So i tries tried raising it to the 2nd 3rd and 4th power to identify a pattern .

I was not able to identify any pattern

I also Tried writing it in terms of an identity matrix.

Comment: Have you studied already eigenvalues, eigenvectors, diagonalization..._

Comment: Try working out $A^2,A^3,A^4$ and see if you can formulate a conjecture and prove it by induction.

Comment: I probably haven't studied under that terminology

Comment: @sidt36 Fine, forget it. I answered your question without that already.

Answer (score 6):

$$A^2=\begin{pmatrix}2&\!-2\\\!-2&2\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;A^3=\begin{pmatrix}4&\!-4\\\!-4&4\end{pmatrix}$$

Can you see a pattern? Good, now prove it by induction.

Comment: Thank you .I was doing the multiplication wrong.If it was this simple I wouldnt have posted it(:

Comment: Indeed. Sometimes we all fall down in the simplest things.